# Passing argument to a .bat file which is user defined file (amongst many .sql files)

Tags: batch-file

Experts,

I have 2 .bat scripts called exportdata.bat and other is importdata.bat. Both are used to take backup of the data. in exportdata.bat i am executing following command

```
:home_defined
%MY_HOME%\database\bin\mysqldump -u root -p mydata>dumpfile.sql
```

and later i am inserting date-timestamp and then renaming it to `dumpfile-20100609-0551PM.sql.`

Each time i execute exportdata.bat, number of times new files with new timestamps generate. After 3 executions, `dumpfile-20100609-0551PM.sql`, `dumpfile-20100609-0552PM.sql` and `dumpfile-20100609-0551PM.sql` are generated. Now in `importdata.bat`, i want to pass an argument of one of these timestamp files like following. This is user defined.

```
importdata.bat dumpfile-20100609-0552PM.sql.
```

Right now in importdata.bat i am executing following command just like `exportdata.bat`:

```
:home_defined
%MY_HOME%\database\bin\mysql -u root -p mydata<dumpfile.sql
```

How should I do it? How should i set the parameter/arguments? Do i need to use dir/?, dir *.sql commands? Please advise/suggest. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty simple:

```
%MY_HOME%\database\bin\mysql -u root -p mydata < %1
```

`%1` gets replaced with the first parameter. `%2` would be the second, etc.